# Getting duplicate emails from SP2010 Workflow, why?

Tags: workflow

Folks, 
   I have a workflow that send analysts emails from a SP library with repeating table.  I'm only grabbing the Last Analyst in the table to send an email to, but I'm actually getting double the emails from it.  My conditions are:

If CurrentItem:Row Number is greater than CurrentItem:Previous Number
and CurrentItem:Current Job status = 5. Completed drilling

Then email primary analyst and log history.

I'm not sure where the duplicate would be coming from

Ideas?

Comment: Is your workflow triggered by another workflow which is set to start when the item is changed? If it is, your workflow could looping if the workflow itself updates the item.

Comment: Are you adding some sort of pause when your workflow completes? There is a known problem if your workflow terminates quickly but the server responds slower that duplicate mails/tasks will be sent/created. http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/solved-sharepoint-2013-custom-workflow-generates-duplicate-email-notifications/

Comment: Kevins,  No, the workflow isn't being triggered by any other workflow.  It's set to fire on Change based on the conditions I mentioned.

Comment: Ransher, I don't have any pauses or waits in the workflow, didn't see a need.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Ransher, I put in a 1 minute pause at the beginning of the WF and now I only get one email.

Comment: Comment: Thanks Kevin.. You saved my day. I never thought of the fact that since I kept my workflow trigger based on change. My other workflows we're making changes hence trigerring the email workflow twice. Thanks again.. Great learning for me.. Thanks again...